# Replacing values columnwise in R

Tags: r, replace

I have a dataframe that look like the following...

```
V1 | V2 | V3 | V4
1  | NA | 2  | 5
NA | 2  | NA | NA
1  | 1  | 1  | 1
```

I would like to transform the dataframe to the following with no header...

```
V1 | NA | V3 | V4
V2 | NA | NA | NA
V1 | V2 | V3 | V4
```

In other words, I want the header name in each cell that I have a number columwise.

Data

```
dd <- read.table(header = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE, sep = '|',
                 text = "V1 | V2 | V3 | V4
                 1  | NA | 2  | 5
                 NA | 2  | NA | NA
                 1  | 1  | 1  | 1")
```

Comment: how are you getting the first two columns. If those are a mistake, I think you want `dd[] <- colnames(dd)[col(dd) * !!dd]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expected output seems strange to me but if I understand well, you want to replace every non-NA by the column name?

You can do like this:

```
df[!is.na(df)] <- rep(names(df), each=nrow(df))[!is.na(df)]
```

given this data:

```
df=data.frame(V1=c(1, NA, 1), V2=c(NA, 2, 1), V3=c(2, NA, 1), V4=c(5, NA, 1))
```

Concerning your wish to get rid of the header, that's impossible in a data.frame. You can transform it into a character matrix and delete the dimnames attributes if you want...

```
df2 = as.matrix(df); attributes(df2)$dimnames<-NULL
```